# VS Code JSON Settings Array Variable

Tags: arrays, json

How can I place John, Bill and Jacob in a single array element.

```json
[{
     "text": "John",
     "color": "#FF00FF",
     "backgroundColor": "rgba(1,1,1,0)",
}, {
     "text": "Bill",
     "color": "#FF00FF",
     "backgroundColor": "rgba(1,1,1,0)",
}, {
     "text": "Jacob",
     "color": "#FF00FF",
     "backgroundColor": "rgba(1,1,1,0)",
}]
```

Comment: Please take the trouble of placing the actual code in your question instead of an image.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
let dest = src.map((x) => x.text);
```

this would yield `['John','Bill','Jacob']`.